# Looking for decent Git libraries for Java

Tags: java, git

I am looking for a decent Git library for Java for stand-alone applications.

Can anyone recommend any?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I believe you can use **[JGit](http://www.eclipse.org/jgit/)** in your Java application.

The main page includes:

> JGit has very few dependencies, making it suitable for embedding in any Java application, whether or not the application is taking advantage of other Eclipse or OSGi technologies.

The [download page](http://eclipse.org/jgit/download/) mentions that:

> JGit can be consumed in a Maven build.
>   Multiple artifacts are available, depending on the application's requirements:

See a full pom.xl in [**`jgit-cookbook/blob/master/pom.xml`**](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/pom.xml):

Extract:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>jgit-repository</id>
      <url>http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/maven</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <!-- Core Library -->
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jgit</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.eclipse.jgit</artifactId>
      <version>3.4.1.201406201815-r</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

The exact list of git commands currently supported is not always up-to-date (as [the bug 317482 illustrates](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=317482)):

Update September 2013 - July 2014: **all the commands below are now available**.

[image]

Comment: Complete with spell-checking squiggles :)

Comment: Some of those half-checks are pretty flimsy, if I recall correctly - I tried to set some IDE-dependent friends up with EGit several months ago and got bitten pretty hard by a lack of non-trivial merge capabilities...

Comment: @Jefromi: only the recent 0.9.x versions are interesting when it comes to merge.

Comment: Aha. I was looking for a good changelog/news/supported features document - at least there's [something on the wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JGit/New_and_Noteworthy). Found it from google, though, not by navigating from the JGit homepage. Looks like they support the resolve strategy now, but still not normal git's default recursive merge.

Comment: @Jefromi: but don't their recent mege test case suggest otherwise? http://egit.eclipse.org/w/?p=jgit.git;a=commitdiff;h=e8642b538c950ad17b3f67c3bf75306b8f78b545 Although their merge algorithm is still shaky: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=328551. Nope, you are right: resolve strategy only for now: http://egit.eclipse.org/w/?p=jgit.git;a=commit;h=45e79a526c7ffebaf8e4758a6cb6b7af05716707

Comment: Would be great if you updated this for recent Jgit - is it still the only option ? duh :(

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D I have updated the answer: all those commands are now available.

Comment: @VonC: thanks - what would be the recommended pom.xml now ?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D the same, but with the latest updated JGit version. I have updated the pom.xml and linked to a full pom.xml updated 5 days ago: https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/pom.xml

Comment: Works for me in Luna with m2e without adding the `<repository>` but still its transitive dependencies may be excluded ?