# Using git via java app

Tags: java, git, command-line

I want to create git repository via my java application. I'm trying to do this this way:

```
builder = new ProcessBuilder(
                "\"C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\sh.exe\" --login" , "git init", "exit");
builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
builder.directory(new File("d:\\repos\\"+newRepoForm.getName()));
p = builder.start();
p.waitFor();
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

But I get exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program ""C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login" (in directory "d:\repos\dgngdn"): CreateProcess error=87, The parameter is incorrect
```

It's the first time I'm doing this kind of stuff, so my mistake can be trivial.

Comment: I think you need to move the "--login" to the second argument. the first needs to be the executable only

Comment: you're right, git opens, but next commands don't work:
"C:/Program Files/Git/bin/sh.exe": git init: No such file or directory

Answer (score 3):

You might find it easier to use a library rather than to invoke git from the command line.  Check out [JGit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193277/looking-for-decent-git-libraries-for-java).

More generally, [libgit2](http://libgit2.github.com/) is also a popular library for many languages but I don't see a Java binding listed (though in theory it wouldn't be too hard to create one using [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna)).

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it, but i'm curious why this particular thing doesn't work

Comment: Similarly, you are telling the shell to execute a command named `git init` but you really want to run the command `git` with `init` as an argument.