# How can we use/access/read file contents of files placed in a private gitlab repository in our java code

Tags: java, maven, gitlab, gitlab-api

I want to use/access/read file contents of files (excel, properties file, etc.) placed in a private gitlab repository in my java code, which would be creating a CSV file as output using the contents of the files from the private gitlab repository.

Comment: Do you mean that the files are stored in git? I ask because Excel is binary, so it's not common to store in version control. If they're stored in git, can't you just do a `git clone`?

Comment: its required for some particular automation project POC. Git clone I can do but how can I achieve that using java code( like when I run that particular jar, the code pulls the required files from the git repo and uses the contents of the files and delete those files later). 
Using jgit ? or any other simple method is there.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to upvote but I have upvoted from my side so it has been recorded as positive feedback.

Comment: Excellent, glad it helped. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the purpose of your Java application is to analyze/control git repositories, then it would make sense to perform the git operations in the JAR. Otherwise, consider calling a simple bash script from a CI/CD pipeline or user.

#### JGit

If your application will need to perform many git operations, [JGit](https://www.eclipse.org/jgit/) is a good option. You can include the dependency in [maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jgit/org.eclipse.jgit) or gradle.

Here's a simple code example to clone a specific branch:

```java
import org.eclipse.jgit.api.Git;
import org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.GitAPIException;

try {
    Git.cloneRepository()
      .setURI("https://github.com/account/repo.git")
      .setDirectory(new File("/path/to/target_directory"))
      .setBranchesToClone(Arrays.asList("refs/heads/branch-name"))
      .setBranch("refs/heads/branch-name")
      .call();
} catch (GitAPIException e) {
    System.err.println("Exception occurred while cloning repo.");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

#### Runtime exec

If you don't want the learning curve of using JGit, or don't want the external dependency, you can also call git commands using the [Runtime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) `exec` method. This requires that git be installed, accessible and authenticated on the host OS. Here's an example:

```java
import java.io.*;

try {
    String cmd = "git clone https://github.com/account/repo.git";
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
}
catch(IOException e)
{
   System.err.println("Exception occurred while executing command.");
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Additional References:**

- [Looking for decent Git libraries for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193277/looking-for-decent-git-libraries-for-java)
- https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JGit/article.html
- https://www.codeaffine.com/2014/12/09/jgit-authentication/
- https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/
- https://www.infoworld.com/article/2071275/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html